Ho to fix nodes not joining to managed-nodes EKS cluster using Amazon EKS Optimized accelerated Amazon Linux AMIs
I am new to EKS and Terraform. I am using Terraform script to create an EKS cluster using GPU nodes. The script eventually throws an error after 20 minutes stating that last error: i-******: NodeCreationFailure: Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster.
Logged in to the node to see what is going on:

systemctl status kubelet => kubelet.service - Kubernetes Kubelet. Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service; disabled; preset: disabled) Active: inactive (dead)
systemctl restart kubelet => Job for kubelet.service failed because of unavailable resources or another system error. See "systemctl status kubelet.service" and "journalctl -xeu kubelet.service" for details.
journalctl -xeu kubelet.service => ...kubelet.service: Failed to load environment files: No such file or directory ...kubelet.service: Failed to run 'start-pre' task: No such file or directory ...kubelet.service: Failed with result 'resources'.

I am using the latest version of this AMI: amazon-eks-node-al2023-x86_64-nvidia-1.31-* as the Kubernetes version is 1.31 and my instance type: g4dn.2xlarge.
I tried many different combinations, but no luck. Any help is appreciated. Here is the relevant portion of my Terraform script:
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "eks_cluster" {
  name     = "${var.branch_prefix}eks_cluster"
  role_arn = module.iam.eks_execution_role_arn

  access_config {
    authentication_mode                         = "API_AND_CONFIG_MAP"
    bootstrap_cluster_creator_admin_permissions = true
  }

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = var.eks_subnets
  }

  tags = var.app_tags
}

resource "aws_launch_template" "eks_launch_template" {
  name          = "${var.branch_prefix}eks_lt"
  instance_type = var.eks_instance_type
  image_id      = data.aws_ami.eks_gpu_optimized_worker.id 

  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/sda1"

    ebs {
      encrypted   = false
      volume_size = var.eks_volume_size_gb
      volume_type = "gp3"
    }
  }

  network_interfaces {
    associate_public_ip_address = false
    security_groups             = module.secgroup.eks_security_group_ids
  }

  user_data = filebase64("${path.module}/userdata.sh")
  key_name  = "${var.branch_prefix}eks_deployer_ssh_key"

  tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.name}" = "owned"
  }
}

resource "aws_eks_node_group" "eks_private-nodes" {
  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.name
  node_group_name = "${var.branch_prefix}eks_cluster_private_nodes"
  node_role_arn   = module.iam.eks_nodes_group_execution_role_arn
  subnet_ids      = var.eks_subnets

  capacity_type  = "ON_DEMAND"

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = var.eks_desired_instances
    max_size     = var.eks_max_instances
    min_size     = var.eks_min_instances
  }

  update_config {
    max_unavailable = 1
  }

  launch_template {
    name    = aws_launch_template.eks_launch_template.name
    version = aws_launch_template.eks_launch_template.latest_version
  }

  tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.name}" = "owned"
  }
}


The issue is likely from userdata.sh. Post this file to your question for further examination if you will.

Yes...thank you for your reply. It turned out the problem has to do with missing nodeadm configuration. Once I added this to my user data like below, it worked right away. I will add the answer below. Thanks again.

It turned out the problem is missing user data to initialize nodeadm (which is a new way in Amazon Linux AL2023). So I added the following to my launch template:
  user_data = base64encode(<<EOF
---
apiVersion: node.eks.aws/v1alpha1
kind: NodeConfig
spec:
  cluster:
    name: ${aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.name}
    apiServerEndpoint: ${aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.endpoint}
    certificateAuthority: ${aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.certificate_authority[0].data}
    cidr: ${aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.kubernetes_network_config[0].service_ipv4_cidr}  
EOF
  )

Here are some references:
User data

Amazon Linux 2023 (AL2023) introduces a new node initialization
process nodeadm that uses a YAML configuration schema. If you’re using
self-managed node groups or an AMI with a launch template, you’ll now
need to provide additional cluster metadata explicitly when creating a
new node group.

